# Prove that $f^{−1} ( \cap ) \subseteq f^{−1} () \cap f^{−1} ()$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone please help in solving this question? I really have no idea how to solve it. [Photo of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh0Ls.png)

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Think about what it means if $x \in f^{-1}(A\cap B)$

Comment: Suppose $x \in f^{-1}(A \cap B)$. [some reasoning here]. Thus $x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$. Pondering the question that J. W. Tanner has posed should lead to you coming up with some reasons which reveal the conclusion to be a consequence of the premise.

Comment: The photo is unnecessary. Your question is clear. Try using the definition of $f^{-1}$ 
 as suggested by J.W. Tanner. This is a straightforward proof and a good exercise for someone just learning how to write proofs.

Comment: hey everyone, thank you soo much for replying so quickly. I think I have got it. I am new here so I don't know how to write in proper format.

Comment: @rdr2 See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @TheoBendit thanks alot. This is really helpful.

Comment: writing in latex is hard to learn all at once. picking up what you can when you can makes the process less overwhelming. people on here should be understanding of the difficulties faced by users new to writing in latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x\in f^{-1}(A\cap B)\implies  f(x)\in A \cap B \implies f(x)\in A $ and $f(x)\in B$

$ \implies x\in f^{-1}(A)$ and $x\in f^{-1}(B) \implies x \in f^{-1}(A) \cap f^{-1}(B)$

Thus, $f^{-1}(A\cap B) \subseteq f^{-1}(A)\cap f^{-1}(B). $

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in f^{-1} (A \cap B).$ Then $$\begin{align} f(x) \in A \cap B. \\ \implies f(x) \in A\ \text {and}\ f(x) \in B. \\ \implies x \in f^{-1} (A)\ \text {and}\ x \in f^{-1} (B). \\ \implies x \in f^{-1} (A) \cap f^{-1} (B). \end{align}$$

Thus, $f^{-1} (A \cap B) \subseteq f^{-1} (A) \cap f^{-1} (B).$

In fact the other part of the inclusion is also true. Can you prove it on your own?

Comment: Yes, infact I did the other part on my own to make my understanding better